# Exclude results with join conditions

Tags: sql, relational-division

I'm trying to make an sql request with join exclusion. 
Explains:

**Table element**

```
id # name #
 1  Sea
 2  tree
```

**Table colour**

```
id # name #
 1    green
 2    blue
 3    brown
```

**Table relation**

```
element_id # colour_id
     1           2
     2           1
     2           3
```

I have my working request for "get elements for one of these colours".
Exemple with green and blue:

```
SELECT element.name, colour.name FROM element
LEFT JOIN relation 
  ON (element.id = relation.element_id)
LEFT JOIN colour
  ON (colour.id = relation.colour_id)
WHERE (relation.colour_id = 1 OR relation.colour_id = 2)
```

I would like make request for **"get elements where they have a relation with all listed colors"**. Where for **green** and **brown** it returns **tree**.

I've tried to change the 'OR' to 'AND' but request return 0 results :/

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem but you missed an 'r' at the end of colour_id.  Otherwise looks ok.

Comment: are you hoping to pass the colors in as a parameter at run time, or just to specify them explicitly in the Where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General way to solve this problem is to filter values and count how many times they appear in result. If equal, all elements are found.

```
select element_id
from relation
where colour_id in (1, 2)
group by element_id
having count (distinct colour_id) = 2
```

Having this table one might join it to original tables to produce full column set:

```
SELECT element.name, colour.name 
  FROM relation 
  INNER JOIN
  (
    select element_id
      from relation
     where colour_id in (1, 2)
     group by element_id
    having count (distinct colour_id) = 2
  ) matches
    ON relation.element_id = matches.element_id
  INNER JOIN element
     ON element.id = relation.element_id
  INNER JOIN colour
     ON colour.id = relation.colour_id
```

Comment: Thank's. I've adapted: Retrieve element_ids with "select ... having count ..." and an where element.id IN (ids) on my main query.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your `WHERE` clause - one of the ids is 2 ("blue") instead of 3 ("brown"). It should be

```
WHERE (relation.colour_id = 1 OR relation.colour_id = 3)
```

(or in shorter form:

```
WHERE relation.colour_id IN (1, 3)
```

).

Note however, that your current query - although after this fix it should work for your sample data - won't give you correct results in general. It will give you the elements associated with *any* of the specified colors. The correct solution to this is given in @Nikola's answer though.

Answer (score 0):

This type of query can be handled with some of SQL's set-based operators:

*Which elements have relations for all colours?*

Using the ALL operator (syntax may vary slightly by database):

```
SELECT element.name
FROM element
WHERE ( SELECT colour.id FROM relation 
      INNER JOIN colour ON colour.id = relation.colour_id
      WHERE relation.element_id = element.id )
= ALL ( SELECT colour.id from colour)
;
```

Using the EXCEPT operator:

```
SELECT element.name
FROM element
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT colour.id from colour
   EXCEPT
  SELECT colour.id FROM relation 
  INNER JOIN colour ON colour.id = relation.colour_id
  WHERE relation.element_id = element.id 
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

without subselects, I would suggest:

```
SELECT
    e.id AS id
FROM
    element AS e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN relation AS r ON r.element_id = e.id
    GROUP BY e.id HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.colour_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) = 0
ORDER BY e.id ASC;
```

after this you can select the elements by id.